# Marketing cloud custom web tab?

Tags: marketing-cloud

On marketing cloud, there exists a bar such as

[image]

Is it possible to add a button where the red box is that is a hyperlink?

Basically i want to add a hyperlink to the menu bar for people using the system.

Answer (score 0):

While not answering the question, I found a way to do something similar.

setup --> admin -- apps --> installed packages --> 
new --> add component --> Marketing cloud app --> enter login and logout link as same link.

Logout and log back in

[image]

not exactly what i was asking for but i think this will work for now unless someone knows how to actually solve this.